# Severless framework : invoke local is giving error - aws lamda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cli, serverless

I have installed aws-cli and serverless in my windows 7 machine from command `npm install -g aws-cli serverless` and also successfully configured `aws` and `sls`

```
aws configure
sls config credentials --provider aws --key <my-access-key> --secret <my-secret-key> --profile serverless-admin
```

Then I created new serverless project

```
sls create -t aws-nodejs
```

Everything worked well till here until when I tried to invoke hello function locally

```
sls invoke local -f hello
Error --------------------------------------------------
Exception encountered when loading E:\Demo\serverless\handler
    For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

[image]

I have tried setting environment variable `set SLS_DEBUG=*` but this does not seem to resolve the issue

I have tried other various solutions available on the net. But doesn't seem to resolve the issue

Thank you for any help.

Comment: is it because the system is old or the os is old?

Comment: I have a same problem.

Comment: i did this same think on ubuntu and it work but when i try it on my windows machine it does not work at all

Comment: if you cd into the project directory and ls to show the files and directories in the project what do you see? how is the lambda defined in the serverless.yml template?